# How to use several times a progress bar in console? - Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm working with `Kotlin` to make a Java console application, which processes some data and using  https://github.com/ctongfei/progressbar to show in console the progres of a loop.

My code:

```
val pb =  ProgressBar("Test Fitness " + fitnessId , maxValueIterator)
for (i in 1..maxValueIterator) {
  ... // Some code not related with the bar
  pb.step(); 
}
```

> I know that this component is for Java, but Kotlin allows the use of
>   these because it transpiles to java when compiling (correct me if I'm
>   wrong).

---

**The problem:**

The problem occurs when the loop is rerun. 
 
The progress bar, is stepped on (*Like a blink with one and another*) with the previous one (*That was already over, and it's 100%*) and sometimes prints many lines with one or the other, both errors happen when the percentage of the current bar increases. 
I am not able to identify where the error is, the documentation shows the same way to use.

Example of error (print many lines simultaneously):

```
Test Fitness 372 100% [==========... // This "Fitness 372" was finished and continues to appear
Test Fitness 299 100% [==========... // The same with this
Test Fitness 921 82% [==========... // This "Fitness 921" is the one that is running
```

Comment: `I know that this component is for Java,` well, it was written in Java, but there's absolutely nothing wrong with using it in Kotlin, nor does it in any way limit you. It doesn't break because you use Kotlin instead of Java

Comment: Are you running your console application from IntelliJ IDEA or from a real terminal?

Comment: In both. In real console is much worse. In IntelliJ IDEA only does the blink effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the different methods of the `ProgressBar` class. 
I discovered that, after completing the use of each progress bar, you need to do `.close()`, if it is not done it is as if you had several instalations in simultaneous.